# Fast run-time vector based std::stack. Pre-allocation and multiple pop

Tags: c++

Is there any **standard** way to have the equivalent of `std::vector:reserve` in a `std::stack<T, std::vector<T>>`?

Also, is there there a **standard** way to implement something like `pop(int count)` and have it destruct elements in the correct order?

If there is no such way, short of writing a custom stack implementation, that would also answer my question.

Comment: Do you mean `std::vector::reserve`?

Comment: `reserve`. Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) can be used with any [*sequence container*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/SequenceContainer), and [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is such a container.

Then you can pass a reference to an existing container (like a pre-allocated vector) to the [`std::stack` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/stack).

Comment: What about the `pop(int)`? Or `for(...) pop()` is the only way?

Comment: @Equilibrius The `std::stack` interface doesn't have such a pop function, you have to use a loop (and be sure to check `empty` too).

Comment: Haven't thought about `empty`. Thanks for that.